# C++ code for meArm arduino robot doesn't work

Tags: arduino, robotics, arduino-c++

I'm having some issues with this code for meArm arduino robot.
It should ask the user to input the values for the angles of the servo motors and rotate them, however it only does so the first 2 times and then stops working.
Is there any error in the code?

```c++
#include <Servo.h>

int angle1;
int angle2;
int angle3;

Servo s1;
Servo s2;
Servo s3;
Servo s4;

const int BUFFER_SIZE = 100;
char buf[BUFFER_SIZE];

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  
  s1.attach(10);
  s2.attach(9);
  s3.attach(8);

  s1.write(90);
  s2.write(0);
  s3.write(0);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("Set the angle for s1 servo");
  while (Serial.available() == 0) {};
  angle1 = Serial.readBytesUntil('\n', buf, BUFFER_SIZE);

  Serial.println("Set the angle for s2 servo");
  while (Serial.available() == 0) {};
  angle2 = Serial.readBytesUntil('\n', buf, BUFFER_SIZE);

  Serial.println("Set the angle for s3 servo");
  while (Serial.available() == 0) {};
  angle3 = Serial.readBytesUntil('\n', buf, BUFFER_SIZE);

  ForwardKinematics(angle1, angle2, angle3);
}

/**
 * Rotates the servo motors by the given angles.
 * 
 * @param angle1 The angle by which the servo s1 is rotated.
 * @param angle2 The angle by which the servo s2 is rotated.
 * @param angle3 The angle by which the servo s3 is rotated.
 */
void ForwardKinematics(int angle1, int angle2, int angle3) {
  s1.write(angle1);
  s2.write(angle2);
  s3.write(angle3);
  delay(500);
}
```

Comment: Note that c++ is not a scripting language, and c++ source codes aren't _"scripts"_. You should adapt your terminology in order not looking awkward.

Comment: Why the while loop on available, the readUntil will do the equivalent for you. Second, readBytesUntil returns the number of bytes read. You need to do `atoi(buf)` to get the entered number

Answer (score 0):

Your biggest problem is,

> Serial.readBytesUntil('\n', buf, BUFFER_SIZE);

will only return the number of characters read into the buffer, not the data. Not sure what you mean by it works the first two times. Do you mean it loops through 2 times, or does it just get data for the first two servos and not the third one. Anyways, below is a working code tested on a UNO.

```c++
#include <Servo.h>

int angle1;
int angle2;
int angle3;

Servo s1;
Servo s2;
Servo s3;
Servo s4;

String data = "";

const int BUFFER_SIZE = 100;
char buf[BUFFER_SIZE];

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  
  s1.attach(10);
  s2.attach(9);
  s3.attach(8);

  s1.write(90);
  s2.write(0);
  s3.write(0);
}

void loop() {
  angle1 = 0;
  angle2 = 0;
  angle3 = 0;
  
  Serial.println("Set the angle for s1 servo");
  while (Serial.available() == 0) {};
  int rlen = Serial.readBytesUntil('\n', buf, BUFFER_SIZE);
  for(int i = 0; i < rlen; i++){
    data += buf[i];
  }
  angle1 = data.toInt();
  data = "";
  
  Serial.println("Set the angle for s2 servo");
  while (Serial.available() == 0) {};
  rlen = Serial.readBytesUntil('\n', buf, BUFFER_SIZE);
  for(int i = 0; i < rlen; i++){
    data += buf[i];
  }
  angle2 = data.toInt();
  data = "";
  
  Serial.println("Set the angle for s3 servo");
  while (Serial.available() == 0) {};
  rlen = Serial.readBytesUntil('\n', buf, BUFFER_SIZE);
  for(int i = 0; i < rlen; i++){
    data += buf[i];
  }
  angle3 = data.toInt();
  data = "";
  

  ForwardKinematics(angle1, angle2, angle3);
}

/**
 * Rotates the servo motors by the given angles.
 * 
 * @param angle1 The angle by which the servo s1 is rotated.
 * @param angle2 The angle by which the servo s2 is rotated.
 * @param angle3 The angle by which the servo s3 is rotated.
 */
void ForwardKinematics(int angle1, int angle2, int angle3) {
  s1.write(angle1);
  s2.write(angle2);
  s3.write(angle3);
  delay(500);
}
```

Comment: If you are going to use `String.toInt()`, won't it be better to just use `Serial.readStringUntil()`? it save you from the `for..loop` and converting the char array to a String object.

Comment: Also the `while (Serial.available() == 0) {};` isn't needed as readUntil is blocking and won't return until a `\n` is received.